# Find the volume between the parabola

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume between the parabola $z=x^2+y^2$and the parabolic cylinder $z=9+x^2$.

I've tried cartesian and cylindrical coordinates to no success

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

If $z = $ junk and $z = $ crud, then at the intersection of the surfaces, junk = crud.  So you have

$$2x^2+y^2 = 4- 3y^2.$$

or

$$x^2+2y^2 = 2.$$

So, as you have probably written, the volume is

$$\iint_D 2(2-x^2-2y^2) \; dA,$$

Where $D$ is the ellipse $x^2+2y^2 = 2$ and its interior. This suggests the substitution $x=\sqrt{2}r\cos t,$ $y=r\sin t$, which has Jacobian $\sqrt{2}r.$

After some details, you get

$$\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1 2(1-r^2)\sqrt{2}r \;dr\;dt.$$

Comment: how did you get the expression in the first double integral?

Comment: Top surface minus bottom surface $= (4-3y^2) - (2x^2+y^2).$

Comment: is it possible to find the integral by using a substitution from the start?

Comment: Probably not.  I don't think there's any way to escape the Jacobian.

Comment: could you show me a method to find the integral without using the top surface minus the bottom surface?

Comment: The exercise says, "Find the volume...".  How are you going to find the volume without knowing the upper and lower bounds of the region?  I knew a guy who claimed he taught his Calc 3 students to do double integrals without graphing.  He was wrong.  You have to graph.

Comment: ok so basically when you are doing top surface minus bottom surface you are integrating z between the two surfaces?

Comment: @Josh99 Why "integrating $\,z\,$" ? The above is a triple integral which, in fact, has been reduced to a double integral. That is not a simple integral.

Comment: If you want to treat it as a triple integral, then you're "integrating 1" between the two surfaces.  After you do the inner integral, you'll have the double integral above.

Comment: yes this is what I meant sorry I get it now

Comment: Also a similar question, finding volume between z=3-2x and z=x^2+y^2,we find the intersection which is z=1, so we integrate II(3-2x-x^2-y^2) over circle radius 1?

Comment: Yes, but it's a circle of radius 2.